# Chained jQuery AJAX with promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently working on a project where 4 get requests are fired simultaneously. I am at the same time using fade effects, and the asynchronous nature of this results in empty data intermittently.

I have been looking into this method as described in
[Prefer way of doing multiple dependent ajax synchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200384/prefer-way-of-doing-multiple-dependent-ajax-synchronous-call) to replace how I am currently doing

```
$.get('ajax_call_1').then(function(value) {
    return $.get('ajax_call_2');
}).then(function(result) {
    // success with both here
}, function(err) {
    // error with one of them here
});
```

But, my question is: How can I access the return from each request individually with the above?

Comment: What's the purpose of accessing them ? Debugging or using it further in the code ? For the debugging a simple `console.log(result)` in each callback should do the trick. If you want to use it further, there are no guarantees you'll already have the result as the code is asynchronous. That's why you use the `Promises`

Comment: Using it further in the code

Comment: Tried it out and it works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said the requests are sent simultaneously. The way you've written your code, they are sent sequentially though. Instead, with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), you can wait for all of the requests' promises and you'll be given an array with the results:

```
Promise.all([
    $.get('ajax_call_1'),
    $.get('ajax_call_2'),
    $.get('ajax_call_3'),
    $.get('ajax_call_4')
]).then(function(results) {
    var first = results[0];
    var second = results[1];
    ...
}).catch(function(err) {
    // called if one of the requests fails
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my post was a bit unclear. The way it's currently set up it's run asyncroneously. The code above is what I have been looking at to replace it

Comment: Okay, now you have me confused. Are you currently doing it the way you wrote in your question or the way I suggested in my answer?